# How to uncheck all state selected rows key using onclick function Table - Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

I have function button where this button need to clear all selected rows key, what happen right now, the state is clear already but still checked on the table. I don't know if my function is right or is there need to change inside my function or use the useEffect. I am using Ant Design for the table and React Js for the front end side.

Here is my Button:

```
<Button type="primary" onClick={unCheckHandler} className="btn-pink">Clear</Button>
```

Here is my handler function:

```
const [selectedRowsKeys, setSelectedRowsKeys] = useState([]);
const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);

const onSelectedRowKeysChange = (selectedRows, selectedRowsKeys) =>{
    setSelectedRows(selectedRows)
    setSelectedRowsKeys(selectedRowsKeys);
}
const rowSelection = {
    selectedRows,
    selectedRowsKeys,
    onChange: onSelectedRowKeysChange
};

const unCheckHandler = () => {
    setSelectedRowsKeys([])
    setSelectedRows([])
}

useEffect(() => {

},[unCheckHandler])

console.log(selectedRowsKeys,"---", selectedRows)
```

Table:

```
    <Table 
    dataSource={props.dataSource} 
    columns={props.columns}
    size="small"
    rowSelection={{
        type: "checkbox",
        ...rowSelection,
    }}
    pagination={false}
/>
```

Sample Log:

[image: sample Log]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `rowSelection.selectedRowKeys` property as per the [Ant Design documentation](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-row-selection). You're only setting `selectedRows` at the moment which doesn't seem to work.

The [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/t7muu) demonstrates how it works.

```
const rowSelection = {
    selectedRowKeys,
    onChange: onSelectedRowKeysChange
};
```

Comment: where should set the rowselection.selectedRowKeys?

Comment: You just need to replace your rowSelection object with the one I provided above.

Comment: based on your given answer it is not working, I add your suggestion on my new details, please see the updated content

Comment: You're setting `selectedRowsKeys`, it needs to be `selectedRowKeys`.